# Error al ingresar un dato al glyphicon

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, css3

al ingresar un dato que tengo en la base de datos en una tabla me sale bien todos los arrays pero al ingresarlo en un glyphicon para que no se vea "feo" se pone en el detalle el mismo de todos los arrays osea no se personaliza alguna sugerencia pls

```
           <td><?php echo $Nticket; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $incidencia; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $tema; ?></td>
                    <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"><li 
               class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></li></a>
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
       </button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Detalle de la incidencia</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p><?php echo $detalle;?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-
     dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

la primera es como no quiero que se vea que se ve desordenado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la segunda es como quiero que quede
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y la tercera es el detalle que aparece en todos los datos del detalle que siempre aparece el mismo sea el dato que sea
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo ajax que carga la tabla y el buscar items

```
include('is_logged.php');//Archivo verifica que el usario que intenta acceder a la URL esta logueado
/* Connect To Database*/
require_once ("../config/db.php");//Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
require_once ("../config/conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos
$action = (isset($_REQUEST['action'])&& $_REQUEST['action'] !=NULL)?$_REQUEST['action']:'';
if (isset($_GET['Nticket'])){
    $incidencia=intval($_GET['Nticket']);
    $query=mysqli_query($con, "select * from ticket where Nticket='".$Nticket."'");
    $rw_user=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $count=$rw_ticket['Nticket'];
    if ($Nticket!=1){
        if ($delete1=mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM ticket WHERE Nticket='".$Nticket."'")){
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <strong>Aviso!</strong> Datos eliminados exitosamente.
        </div>
        <?php 
    }else {
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <strong>Error!</strong> Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente.
        </div>
        <?php

    }

    } else {
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <strong>Error!</strong> No se pudo eliminar ésta  categoría. Existen productos vinculados a ésta categoría. 
        </div>
        <?php
    }



}
if($action == 'ajax'){
    // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
     $q = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_REQUEST['q'], ENT_QUOTES)));
     $aColumns = array('Nticket');//Columnas de busqueda
     $sTable = "ticket";
     $sWhere = "";
    if ( $_GET['q'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".$q."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }
    $sWhere.=" order by Nticket";
    include 'pagination.php'; //include pagination file
    //pagination variables
    $page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page']))?$_REQUEST['page']:1;
    $per_page = 10; //how much records you want to show
    $adjacents  = 4; //gap between pages after number of adjacents
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
    //Count the total number of row in your table*/
    $count_query   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $sTable  $sWhere");
    $row= mysqli_fetch_array($count_query);
    $numrows = $row['numrows'];
    $total_pages = ceil($numrows/$per_page);
    $reload = './clientes.php';
    //main query to fetch the data
    $sql="SELECT * FROM  $sTable $sWhere LIMIT $offset,$per_page";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    //loop through fetched data
    if ($numrows>0){
        ?>
    <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table">
            <tr  class="danger">
                <th>ticket</th>
                <th>Incidencia</th>
                <th>Tema</th>
                <th>Detalle</th>
            </tr>
                <?php
        $nums=1;
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                    $Nticket=$row['Nticket'];
                    $incidencia=$row['incidencia'];
                    $tema=$row['tema'];
                    $detalle=$row['detalle'];



                    ?>


                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['Nticket'];?>" id="Nticket<?php echo $Nticket;?>">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['incidencia'];?>" id="incidencia<?php echo $incidencia;?>">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['tema'];?>" id="tema<?php echo $tema;?>">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['detalle'];?>" id="detalle<?php echo $detalle;?>">

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $Nticket; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $incidencia; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $tema; ?></td>
                    <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"><li 
                   class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></li></a>
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
           <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
              </button>
           <h4 class="modal-title">Detalle de la incidencia</h4>
       </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <p><?php echo $detalle;?></p>
     </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-
           dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
      </div>

          </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Kevin, no se entiende tu pregunta podrías ser más específico o añadir imágenes de tu resultado final y tu resultado esperado ?

Comment: listo ya lo subi las 3 img

Comment: Sería bueno que subieras el código completo, donde haces el recorrido para generar los tr de la tabla?

Comment: ok ya subo los codigos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba haciendo lo siguiente

```
include('is_logged.php');//Archivo verifica que el usario que intenta acceder a la URL esta logueado
/* Connect To Database*/
require_once ("../config/db.php");//Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
require_once ("../config/conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos
$action = (isset($_REQUEST['action'])&& $_REQUEST['action'] !=NULL)?$_REQUEST['action']:'';
if (isset($_GET['Nticket'])){
    $incidencia=intval($_GET['Nticket']);
    $query=mysqli_query($con, "select * from ticket where Nticket='".$Nticket."'");
    $rw_user=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $count=$rw_ticket['Nticket'];
    if ($Nticket!=1){
        if ($delete1=mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM ticket WHERE Nticket='".$Nticket."'")){
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <strong>Aviso!</strong> Datos eliminados exitosamente.
        </div>
        <?php 
    }else {
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <strong>Error!</strong> Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente.
        </div>
        <?php

    }

    } else {
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <strong>Error!</strong> No se pudo eliminar ésta  categoría. Existen productos vinculados a ésta categoría. 
        </div>
        <?php
    }



}
if($action == 'ajax'){
    // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
     $q = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_REQUEST['q'], ENT_QUOTES)));
     $aColumns = array('Nticket');//Columnas de busqueda
     $sTable = "ticket";
     $sWhere = "";
    if ( $_GET['q'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".$q."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }
    $sWhere.=" order by Nticket";
    include 'pagination.php'; //include pagination file
    //pagination variables
    $page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page']))?$_REQUEST['page']:1;
    $per_page = 10; //how much records you want to show
    $adjacents  = 4; //gap between pages after number of adjacents
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
    //Count the total number of row in your table*/
    $count_query   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $sTable  $sWhere");
    $row= mysqli_fetch_array($count_query);
    $numrows = $row['numrows'];
    $total_pages = ceil($numrows/$per_page);
    $reload = './clientes.php';
    //main query to fetch the data
    $sql="SELECT * FROM  $sTable $sWhere LIMIT $offset,$per_page";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    //loop through fetched data
    if ($numrows>0){
        ?>
    <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table">
            <tr  class="danger">
                <th>ticket</th>
                <th>Incidencia</th>
                <th>Tema</th>
                <th>Detalle</th>
            </tr>
                <?php
        $nums=0;
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                    $Nticket=$row['Nticket'];
                    $incidencia=$row['incidencia'];
                    $tema=$row['tema'];
                    $detalle=$row['detalle'];

                    $nums++;



                    ?>


                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['Nticket'];?>" id="Nticket<?php echo $Nticket;?>">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['incidencia'];?>" id="incidencia<?php echo $incidencia;?>">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['tema'];?>" id="tema<?php echo $tema;?>">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['detalle'];?>" id="detalle<?php echo $detalle;?>">

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $Nticket; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $incidencia; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $tema; ?></td>
                    <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal_<?php echo $nums; ?>"><li 
                   class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></li></a>
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal_<?php echo $nums; ?>" role="dialog">
           <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
              </button>
           <h4 class="modal-title">Detalle de la incidencia</h4>
       </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <p><?php echo $detalle;?></p>
     </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-
           dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
      </div>

          </div>
     </div>
```

En resumen:

1. A tu variable `$nums` asígnale un incrementable `$num++` dentro de tu ciclo while
2. El valor del atributo `href` de la etiqueta `<a>` que abre el modal cambialo a `"#myModal_<?php echo $nums; ?>"`
3. El valor del atributo `id` de tu modal cambialo a `"myModal_<?php echo $nums; ?>"`

Espero que te funcione, saludos !

EXPLICACIÓN

Cuando estabas pintando las etiquetas `<a>` y los `modal` en tu código, siempre quedaban con el mismo `id`, es decir las etiquetas `<a>` apuntaban siempre al mismo `id` del modal, es por eso que con la variable `$nums` se hace el `id` dinámico agregando un número único al final.

Comment: no me convence la repuesta.... ok no gracias crack otra vez  v.e.r

Comment: ¿Te funcionó? Excelente ! Te edité la respuesta con la explicación de lo que estaba pasando con tu código para que lo entiendas mejor, saludos !

Comment: vale crack ah listo gracias por la explicacion lo aplicare para la proxima